# 4K HDMI output from MacMini (late 2018) to LG C8 (OLED55C8PLA)

Tags: mac-mini, hdmi, 4k

The LG TV just says "no signal". I'm connecting the Mac Mini to another TV just fine (1080p though). I'm using the same cable to connect a Windows 10 machine and it works over 4K just fine.

Is there some setting I need to set in order to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I had to do to make it work:

1. Upgrade WebOS to latest version
2. Switch to appropriate HDMI input (HDMI2 in my case)
3. Turn ON "ULTRA HD Deep Colour" for HDMI2 (pictured below)

[image: ULTRA HD Deep Colour ON]

Comment: I had a similar problem with and LG 4K TV  - everything worked except an HDMI support.  LG swapped out the main board and suddenly my 4K support from a PC stopped working.  It too was fixed with a firmware update.  I had forgotten about it until I saw this post!  Thanks for sharing as this will definitely help someone else!

Comment: I just bought a new Mac mini to run as a headless computer, and had the same problem with my LG C8 when I was trying to set it up. At first the Mac mini displayed on my LG C8, but once I upgraded the software on the Mac mini during initial setup, the LG and mini did not connect. This post saved my bacon. Thank you.

Comment: Ohhhh man! Thank you so much! Was about to return my LG 43UM73. The "ULTRA HD Deep Color" option did the trick. Before I turned it on, I only had 30 HZ refresh rate. After I turned it on, now have 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz. Note - I'm using an USB-C (on Mac mini) to HDMI (on LG TV) cable for the connection.